# List, Count elements, but properties not available

Tags: jquery, properties, syntax-error

I am able list all the elements and get a  count of the li elements, but I cannot get any properties of the elements.

Even document.getElementById does not return anything.

Can anyone see why - it does not seem possible that I can list and count items, but not get any properties.

The script is at the bottom of the page and calls $().ready function

```js
  $().ready(function () {
        $("*").each(function (i, e) {
            if (e == '[object HTMLLIElement]') {
                console.log(i + '-' + e);
            }
        });

        var docHeight = $(document).height();
        var docWidth = $(document).width();

        var teams = $('#teamsList').children().length
        var rungs = $('#ladderList').children().length
        var blankrungs = $('#ladderList').children('.blankrung').length
        var teamrungs = $('#ladderList').children('.teamrung').length
        var teamslistHeight = docHeight - 300;
        var teamslistWidth = teamslistHeight / 25 //console.log($('#teamsList li').first.height);
        var team42 = document.getElementById('#team42')

        // OK
        console.log('docHeight' + ' ' + docHeight)
        console.log('docWidth' + ' ' + docWidth)
        console.log('teams' + ' ' + teams)
        console.log('blankrungs' + ' ' + blankrungs)
        console.log('teamrungs' + ' ' + teamrungs)
        console.log('rungs' + ' ' + rungs)
        console.log('teamslistHeight' + ' ' + teamslistHeight)
        console.log('teamslistWidth' + ' ' + teamslistWidth)
        console.log($('#teamsList').children().first()) //lists all object properties
        console.log($('#teamsList'))//lists all object properties

        // do not work
        console.log($('#teamsList li').first.height);
        console.log(document.getElementById('#team42'))  //null
        console.log(team42)                              //null
        console.log('#team42' + ' ' + $('#team42').Text) //undefined
        //console.log('innerText' + ' ' + $('#teamsList').children().first().innerText()) // uncaught type error
        //console.log('team42' + ' ' + team42.Text)// uncaught type error
    });
```

```html
'VB Razor
        <ul id="teamsList" class="connectedSortable flex-container-teams column">
            @For Each Rung As UserIrrationaListItem In (From i In Model.UserIrrationaListItems).Where(Function(w) w.PositionId = 0).OrderByDescending(Function(o) o.Colour1).ThenBy(Function(o) o.Colour2).ThenBy(Function(o) o.PositionId).ToList

                @<li id="@("team" + Rung.Id.ToString)" Class="sortable-item flex-item team" Style="background-color:@Rung.HexColour1; color:@Rung.HexColour2" ;
                   @Html.Raw(Rung.Name.ToString + " " + Rung.PositionId.ToString + "-" + Rung.RungId.ToString)
                </li>
            Next
        </ul>
```

html created for li element

```
<li id="team42" class="sortable-item flex-item team ui-sortable-handle" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#000000" ;>
Darlington 0-46
```

Comment: It's a series of typo-level errors. (We've all made typo-level errors. :-) ) I'll write you up a list, but I recommend reading through the [jQuery API](https://api.jquery.com/) documentation and just generally the documentation of the things you're using (for instance, [`getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)). For instance, `document.getElementById('#team42')` should be `document.getElementById('team42')` -- `getElementById` accepts an **ID** value, not a CSS selector.

Comment: Here's the list: *"`console.log($('#teamsList li').first.height);`"* `first` and `height` are both **methods**, not data properties, you need to use `()` to call them: `console.log($('#teamsList li').first().height());` *"`console.log(document.getElementById('#team42'))`"* Shouldn't have the `#` in the ID value as I mentioned above. *"`console.log('#team42' + ' ' + $('#team42').Text)`"* It's `text`, not `Text`, and again it's a method, not a data property. There may be other similar errors, just keep a keen eye out for detail and refer to the docs as needed. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

I had assumed that it was syntax errors causing the problem. I thought I had tried all possible varieties of case and brackets, but your comments have helped me get it sorted.

The revised code is

```js
    $().ready(function () {
        $("*").each(function (i, e) {
            if (e == '[object HTMLLIElement]') {
                console.log(i + '-' + e);
            }
        });

        var docHeight = $(document).height();
        var docWidth = $(document).width();

        var teams = $('#teamsList').children().length
        var rungs = $('#ladderList').children().length
        var blankrungs = $('#ladderList').children('.blankrung').length
        var teamrungs = $('#ladderList').children('.teamrung').length
        var teamslistHeight = docHeight - 300;
        var teamslistWidth = teamslistHeight / 25 //console.log($('#teamsList li').first.height);
        var team42 = document.getElementById('team42')

        // OK
        console.log('docHeight' + ' ' + docHeight)
        console.log('docWidth' + ' ' + docWidth)
        console.log('teams' + ' ' + teams)
        console.log('blankrungs' + ' ' + blankrungs)
        console.log('teamrungs' + ' ' + teamrungs)
        console.log('rungs' + ' ' + rungs)
        console.log('teamslistHeight' + ' ' + teamslistHeight)
        //console.log('teamslistWidth' + ' ' + teamslistWidth)
        console.log($('#teamsList').children().first())
        console.log($('#teamsList'))

        console.log($('#teamsList li').first().height());
        console.log(document.getElementById('team42'))  
        console.log(team42)                             
        console.log('#team42' + ' ' + $('#team42').text())
        console.log('innerText' + ' ' + $('#teamsList').children().first().text())
        console.log('team42' + ' ' + team42.innerText)
    });
```